# Online service for redirecting to custom URL

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting

I would like to use a service which will be an HTTPS link. I want to provide it a URL as a parameter. E.g. https://example.com?skype://abc. When a user visits the complete link, the service will simply redirect the user to the URL given in the parameter. Are such services available?